# DELETE IN with explode()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have a form that submits an array of transaction IDs to `$_POST['transid']` so those transaction records can be deleted.

I typically use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to help prevent attacks, but I am not sure how to go about it with an array.  The following is my query:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE (transid) IN ("'.implode('","',$_POST[transid]).'")'
```

...which gives me something like this:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE (transid) IN ("123","124","138","145")'
```

This seems to be asking for trouble.  How can I protect myself from disaster (malicious or otherwise)?  Is there an efficient way to sanitize the array?  Or should I go about this another way?

Any thoughts or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Loop through the post trnsid and check if its all int

Comment: Use PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: @Mihai: It's a little tricky using prepared statements with a variable number of values.  Also, MySQLi also supports prepared statements.

Comment: @RocketHazmat One does not exclude the other..But I`m curious,how would you use variable number of parameters for prepared statements?

Comment: If you don't want to use prepared statements, you could also filter not integer values by using `array_filter($_POST['transid'], 'ctype_digit')`

Comment: Other way you can take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10722827/937367

Comment: @Mihai: It was your suggestion.  Anyway, you'd have to count the number of elements and add that many `?`s, then probably use `call_user_func_array()` to call the `bind_param` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably better off sanitizing the $_POST before you use it to implode and for that you'll have to traverse it. @user870018 beat me to the punch on the structure but here's what I'd do anyway:

```
function sanitize($n)
{
    return your_escape_function_here($n);
}

$values = implode(",", array_map("sanitize", $_POST[transid]));
$query = 'DELETE FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE (transid) IN ('.$values.')';
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  This is pretty much the direction that I was thinking I'd need to take this, but validation from other people always helps, as well as an example to work off of in my testing.

Answer (score 2):

Use a foreach loop before building your query;

```
foreach ($_POST[transid] as &$x) $x = your_escape_function_here($x);
```

Or (if you use arrays in this manner regularly) build it into a function to keep the overall program a bit cleaner;

```
function sqlEscapeArray($arr){
foreach ($arr as &$x)
$x = your_escape_function_here($x);
return $arr;
}
```

Then use it like so;

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM TRANSACTIONS WHERE (transid) IN ("'.implode('","',sqlEscapeArray($_POST[transid])).'")';
```

Of course, replace your_escape_function with, well.... Your escape function.